# Asp.Net leave comments ability

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page where a User have the ability to leave a comment. When the user clicks submit this comment stored on db table. With the post back the datagrid I have databind() and the comment displayed on the datagrid I have. I want to present the comment with more elegant way. Now it is like a classic datagrid. I would like to be like the web pages where you can leave a comment at the bottom of the page.
My code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <strong>Post Comment</strong><br />
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert">
 <InsertItemTemplate> 
Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
 Comments:<br />
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' 
TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidTimeDate" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CommentDate") %>' />
 <asp:Button ID="butSubmit" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" /> </InsertItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>

<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server"  
Width="593px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
GridLines="None">
 <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 <EditItemStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
 <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
 <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
 <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
 </asp:DataGrid>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [UserID], [CommentDate], [Comments] FROM [Comments]"
         InsertCommand="INSERT Comments (UserID,Comments,CommentDate) VALUES (@UserID, @Comments, @CommentDate)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: *I want to present the comment with more elegant way. Now it is like a classic datagrid. I would like to be like the web pages where you can leave a comment at the bottom of the page.* You have to start implementing that and come back when you have a more concrete question about that topic.

Comment: use pure client side code jquery ajax and html to achieve it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't get what you would like to do exactly,but i think you want to make the last comment row inside the grid with a new style...

you can do this by making the last comment on top of the grid rows and call function 
`onRowDataBound()` ,and check if it's 1st row change the row style

**#Update**

i see that you already making each row with a different background color using these

```
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
 <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
```

Now about the font ,you can create Template field which you can hold its styling
like this

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Bind" Text='Eval(YOUR DATA HERE)' CssClass="CSS-CLASSS" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: I would like a page with comments like:http://www.programmersheaven.com/article/100684-AJAX-Enabled+Comment+Form+in+ASP.NET+and+C%23/info.aspx

Comment: you want the same grid style or the functionality?